# Range validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

Suppose I have a table like:

```
create table
{
id numeric(5,3),
code varchar(10)
}
```

I have two text boxes in my form for the two fields.

Suppose if I type `1234578` in the first text box the error has been thrown in ASP.NET because I crossed the limit.

How can I validate in JavaScript or some other way for that particular range validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take one textbox only. Attach an 'onchange' event handler to your textbox like this:

```
<input type="text" onchange="handleChange(this);" />
```

Then declare a script for validation like this:

```
<script>
  function handleChange(input) {
    if (input.value > ..your_value_here..) alert ("Invalid input");
  }
</script>
```

Please note that the alert pop-up used here should **not** be actually used. Use a more subtle reminder at a more appropriate moment. The alert here is only to make things simple.

Comment: script>  function handleChange(input) {    if (input.value > 5,3) alert ("Invalid input");  }</script>

is it right

Comment: No, if you want the range to be within 3 and 5, use this if clause: if(input.value < 3 || input.value > 5) alert(...